# What is best way to get highest bitmap representation from NSImage object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, image-processing, bitmap, nsimage

I want to fetch highest NSBitmapImageRep from NSImage object.
For example if NSImage object contain:

```
NSIconRefBitmapImageRep 0x1272d0 Size={128, 128} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=8 BPP=32 Pixels=128x128 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=0 CurrentBacking=nil (faulting),
NSIconRefBitmapImageRep 0x11b330 Size={256, 256} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=8 BPP=32 Pixels=256x256 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=0 CurrentBacking=nil (faulting),
NSIconRefBitmapImageRep 0x19fe10 Size={512, 512} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=8 BPP=32 Pixels=512x512 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=0 CurrentBacking=nil (faulting),
NSIconRefBitmapImageRep 0x124d10 Size={32, 32} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=8 BPP=32 Pixels=32x32 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=0 CurrentBacking=nil (faulting),
NSIconRefBitmapImageRep 0x142180 Size={16, 16} ColorSpace=Generic RGB colorspace BPS=8 BPP=32 Pixels=16x16 Alpha=YES Planar=NO Format=0 CurrentBacking=nil (faulting)
```

then i want {512 , 512} representation. I am using below code for this.

```
NSBitmapImageRep* requiredBitmap = nil;
    BOOL setValue =NO;

    NSEnumerator* imageEnum = [[origImage representations] objectEnumerator];

    while( imagerep = [imageEnum nextObject])
    {
        if ([imagerep isKindOfClass:[NSBitmapImageRep class]]) 
        {
            if (!setValue) {
                requiredBitmap = imagerep;
                setValue =YES;
            }
            if ([requiredBitmap pixelsHigh]<[imagerep pixelsHigh]) {
                requiredBitmap = imagerep;

                NSLog(@"%d", [imagerep pixelsHigh]);

            }
        }
    }


    NSImage* original512Image;

    if( requiredBitmap )
    {
        original512Image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[requiredBitmap TIFFRepresentation]];


}
```

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `bestRepresentationForRect:context:hints:` with a very large rect (perhaps `CGRectInfinite`)?

Comment: this method is available in Mac OS X v10.6 and later. and i am looking solution for Leopard os.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using

```
id imageRep = nil;

NSSize largImageSize;

BOOL setValue =NO;

NSEnumerator* imageEnum = [[lOriginalImage representations] objectEnumerator];

while((imageRep = [imageEnum nextObject])) {

    if (!setValue) {
        largImageSize = [imageRep size];
        setValue =YES;
    }
    else if ((largImageSize.height) < ([imageRep size].height)) {
        largImageSize = [imageRep size];
    }

}


[lOriginalImage setSize:largImageSize];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using fast enumeration, but apart from that your method is about as efficient as you can get for Leopard.

Even so, the overhead of looping through five image reps and checking their dimensions will be extremely small, just a few accessor method calls.

Remember, first profile, then optimise. Pre-emptive optimisation is a waste of time.

```
NSBitmapImageRep* requiredBitmap = nil;
BOOL setValue =NO;

for(NSImageRep* imagerep in [origImage representations])
{
    if ([imagerep isKindOfClass:[NSBitmapImageRep class]]) 
    {
        if (!setValue) {
            requiredBitmap = imagerep;
            setValue =YES;
        }
        if ([requiredBitmap pixelsHigh]<[imagerep pixelsHigh]) {
            requiredBitmap = imagerep;

            NSLog(@"%d", [imagerep pixelsHigh]);

        }
    }
}


NSImage* original512Image = nil;
if( requiredBitmap )
{
    original512Image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[requiredBitmap TIFFRepresentation]];
}
```